# Delete objects with repeated keyname parse.com

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform, pfquery

I have a class on parse.com, that contains many objects. One of the keys of each object, is the name of a country. How can I programatically delete all objects with a repeated country name key. The only way I can think of is very longwinded, so any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

This is the best I could come up with.

```
var objectId = [String]()
        var Country = [String]()
        var city = [String]()
        var deletes = [String]()
        var query = PFQuery(className: "Route")
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            for object in objects {
                objectId.append(object.objectId)
                Country.append(object["Country"] as String)
                city.append(object["Start"] as String)
            }
            println(objectId)
            println(Country)
            var i = Int()
            for i=0; i < objectId.count; i++ {

                var j = Int()
                for j = i + 1 ; j < objectId.count; j++ {
                    if Country[i] == Country[j] {
                        println(objectId[j])
                        var deleteQuery = PFQuery(className: "Route")
                        deleteQuery.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(objectId[j], block: { (object: PFObject!, error2: NSError!) -> Void in
                            if error2 == nil {
                                object.delete()
                            }
                        })

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I'm convinced there must be a simpler way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could make the duplicate search a little skinnier by creating an `NSMutableSet` of country names.  Run through the returned objects adding the country names to the set, [testing membership](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSSet/member:) beforehand.  If a an object's country is in the set already, add it to a mutable array of of `duplicates`.

The deletion part of your code can be much improved.  After the set-based test fills the duplicates array, use `PFObject(deleteAllInBackground:duplicates)`  This will replace all of the code beginning at `for i=0; i < objectId.count; i++ {`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately I only started developing recently and am only familiar with swift, and  [PFObject deleteAllInBackground:duplicates]; looks suspiciously like objective-C? I'm also not entirely sure where I would implement this. Thanks for any further help

Answer (score 1):

The way you have done it is correct, just remember to change the limit from the default of 100 to 1000.

If you need to do it on a table/class with more than 1000 rows then you'll need to create a server-side job to do it and use the `query.each()` function to iterate over all the rows, then clean up the duplicates.